# How to call JS function with in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am working in view file of opencart. I have 2 text boxes which set date and time respectively. I have a checkbox, its value is 1 when checked and 0 when not checked.What I want is that date and time fields should be hidden if above check box is checked (Done till now).If checkbox is unchecked, show these fields as they are now(Done till now). 
Current code:

HTML

```
<tr id="row_ship_date">
    <td>
        Shipment Date:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="ship_date" name="ship_date" class="date" onchange="getServices();" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_ship_time">
    <td>
        Shipment Time:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="ship_time" name="ship_time" class="time" />
    </td>
</tr> 

<?php   
    if (isset($current_date_shipment) && $current_date_shipment == 1) // check box value check{?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('row_ship_date').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('row_ship_time').style.display='none';
            getServices();
        </script>
    <?php }
?>
```

JS:

```
function getServices()      {
    alert('test');
    var ship_date = $('#ship_date').val();
    var ship_time = $('#ship_time').val();
    // code so on..
}
```

**Current issues**

1) I am unable to call `getServices()` if checkbox check is true (php check of `if` statement) because if its false it gets call onchange event of date and works fine.

2) how can I set current date and current time respectively for both text fields if this function is called under `if` statement (when both fields are hidden), something like:

```
function getServices()      {
    alert('test');
    var ship_date = new Date();
    var ship_time = currentTime();
    // code so on..
}
```

Comment: Check your browser console when the PHP condition is true..there might be JS errors.

Comment: If your PHP condition is returning true there seems to be no problem with the code(not considering the comment statement // check box value check which is also commenting the curly brace "{" )

Comment: @techie_28 but why my function is not getting called (JS function).

Comment: Did you check your browser console for errors?..is the PHP condition block executing?.. put an echo statement inside to confirm..if there is no JS/PHP error your implementation should work.

Comment: @techie_28 console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: getServices is not defined" but i have defined it under my html

Comment: fn getServices is defined below your PHP to JS function call,move it above that & it should fix it.

Comment: @techie_28 ok fine. what about the 2nd issue i mentioned in que? i mean how can i use current date and time to this function if my date and time fields are hidden should i use hidden fields?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because you are trying to call the function before declaring it.
    Try to wrap you code inside

```
<script>
// self executing function
(function() {
  // put your code here

})();
</script>
```

i.e;

```
   <?php   
            if (isset($current_date_shipment) && $current_date_shipment == 1) // check box value check
   {?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  (function() {
            document.getElementById('row_ship_date').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('row_ship_time').style.display='none';
            getServices();
         })();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?php   
            if (isset($current_date_shipment) && $current_date_shipment == 1) {
                $now = new DateTime();
                $date = $now->format('Y-m-d');
                $time = $now->format('H:i');
?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#row_ship_date,#row_ship_time').hide();
                    $('#ship_date').val(<?php echo $date; ?>);// this should set date value,Use appropriate PHP function.
                    $('#ship_time').val(<?php echo $time; ?>); // this should set time value,Use appropriate PHP function.
                    getServices();
                </script>
            <?php } ?>
```

You dont need hidden fields to set any value but can set as shown above using the jQuery `.val()`.

Just replace the "new date/time value here strings" with PHP variables containing the corresponding values or use the appropriate PHP functions to get it.

Also ensure that jQuery & your function definition of `getServices` exists before your PHP condition executes.

Comment: i tried ur code and got error in console "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" for date time variables is used this code "<?php $now = new DateTime(); $date = $now->format('Y-m-d'); $time =  $now->format('H:i'); ?>"

Comment: did you remove your own comment // check box value check before executing?..check my edits to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your syntax has a problem. You can not invoke Javascript inside a PHP script. This part here:

```
<?php   if (isset($current_date_shipment) && $current_date_shipment == 1) // check box value check{?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('row_ship_date').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('row_ship_time').style.display='none';
getServices();
// <---- notice also here you have no </script> tag :)
<?php }?>
```

I am just pointing out some minor syntax problem :)

Comment: my bad actually i have this ending tag editing my que. how should i invoke than

Comment: I see, if you wish to allow communication between PHP and Javascript you must be able to use AJAX. That is the only way that you can allow communication between PHP and JAVASCRIPT.